# Transferring a login from the browser to my app

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent

I'm trying to transfer a user which is logged in into a mobile-website, to a yet to be installed app.

So the app is not yet installed and you can't use a special intent link to login into the app.

Some options I see:

- I was thinking about using the [installreferrer api](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/) but it is way to unreliable for logging in.
- And I was thinking about using some kind of cookie in the browser, But I couldn't find a good and reliable injection for this.
- Any other suggestions?